# Woocommerce how to display products by product SKU

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

One my client want to display all woocommerce product by product `SKU`.

Normally i used following code for display products.

```
$postArg = array('post_type'=>'product',
                            'post_status'=>'publish',
                            'posts_per_page'=>-1,
                            'orderby'=>'data',
                            'order'=>'DESC',

                    );

            $queryGetFiles = get_posts($postArg);
```

But now my client want to show all products by product `SKU` in front side.

SKU like this 1041-14, 1041-12, 1041-16 ,1041,2001,3501

all product has different sku value and display which doesn't have `"-"` character

Anyone know how should i do this?

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean in the order of the SKU? so 100001 would be followed by 100002 etc.?

Comment: all product has different sku value and display which doesn't have "-" character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You All guys for support.

I have resolved it by my self using following.

```
$postArg = array('post_type'=>'product',
                            'post_status'=>'publish',
                            'posts_per_page'=>-1,
                            'orderby'=>'date',
                            'order'=>'DESC',
                            'meta_query' => array(
                                    array(
                                            'key' => '_sku',
                                            'value' => '-',
                                            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
                                    )
                                ),
                    );
```

Answer (score 6):

Try this

```
$postArg = array(
       'post_type'      => 'product',
       'post_status'    => 'publish',
       'posts_per_page' => -1,
       'meta_key'       => '_sku',
       'orderby'        => 'meta_value' // meta_value_num if ordered by intergers
       'order'          => 'DESC',
);

$queryGetFiles = get_posts($postArg);
```

[Answered with help of this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/30241/wp-query-order-results-by-meta-value)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as the question was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Try to put code in function.php

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
    function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
        $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
        $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value_num';
        $args['order'] = 'desc'; 
        return $args;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. Let me know if this works perfectly....

```html
/**
 * Adds the ability to sort products in the shop based on the SKU
 * Can be combined with tips here to display the SKU on the shop page: https://www.skyverge.com/blog/add-information-to-woocommerce-shop-page/
 */

function sv_add_sku_sorting( $args ) {

 $orderby_value = isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) ? wc_clean( $_GET['orderby'] ) : apply_filters( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby', get_option( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby' ) );

 if ( 'sku' == $orderby_value ) {
  $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value';
      $args['order'] = 'asc'; 
      // ^ lists SKUs alphabetically 0-9, a-z; change to desc for reverse alphabetical
  $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
 }

 return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'sv_add_sku_sorting' );


function sv_sku_sorting_orderby( $sortby ) {
 $sortby['sku'] = 'Sort by SKU';
 // Change text above as desired; this shows in the sorting dropdown
 return $sortby;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'sv_sku_sorting_orderby' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'sv_sku_sorting_orderby' );
```

Comment: User wants to display products sort by SKU (ascending)

Comment: This seems to be valuable. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It seems later versions of woo-commerce have added a manual drag-and-drop sort on the product pages and this overrides any function we use to try and order by SKU. The following worked for me.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'custom_sort_products_by_sku' );

function custom_sort_products_by_sku( $query ) {
// Check if on a product category archive page
if ( ! is_admin() && is_product_category() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    // Set the orderby parameter to 'meta_value' for SKU
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    // Set the meta key to '_sku' which is the SKU
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_sku' );
    // Set the order parameter to 'ASC' for ascending order
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
}

// Add the 'Sort by SKU' option to the 
sorting dropdown
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 
'add_sort_by_sku_to_dropdown' );
function add_sort_by_sku_to_dropdown( $options ) {
// Add 'Sort by SKU' option
$options['sort_by_sku'] = __('Sort by SKU', 'woocommerce');
return $options;
}

// Handle the sorting logic for 'Sort by SKU'
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'sort_products_by_sku' );
function sort_products_by_sku( $query ) {
// Check if 'orderby' is set to 'sort_by_sku'
if ( isset( $_GET['orderby'] ) && 'sort_by_sku' === $_GET['orderby'] ) {
    $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value' );
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_sku' );
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
}
}

// Ensure the 'Sort by SKU' option works correctly with WooCommerce's session 
handling
add_filter( 'woocommerce_default_catalog_orderby_options', 'add_sort_by_sku_to_dropdown' );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_catalog_orderby', 'add_sort_by_sku_to_dropdown' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I registered just now to reply.

I had the same exact issue with a customer who wanted her products sorted by sku. The scripts above order the products by the general Wordpress id and not the product sku. The following is what sorted the products by the sku:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby');
function am_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $args ) {
    $args['meta_key'] = '_sku';
    $args['orderby'] = '_sku';
    $args['order'] = 'asc'; 
    return $args;
}
```